# How do I bring an MS Outlook 2007 dialog to the front from MS Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access, vba, outlook

I am attempting to allow a user of a MS Access 2007 database to select another user from the MS Outlook GAL. I currently have working code that opens the Outlook Select Names Dialog, but it hides behind the database window until a user clicks on Outlook.

How do I make the dialog visible to the user in VBA?

Here's my code for the dialog (typos are a result of a manual copy--this code is on an airgapped network):

```
set OLApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
set OLDialog = OLApp.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog
with OLDialog
    .SetDefaultDisplayMode olDefaultSingleName
    if .Display then
        if OLDialog.Recipients.Count then
            theUser = OLDialog.Recipients.Item(1)
        end if
    end if
end with
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this work by adding the following line after `.SetDefaultDisplayMode olDefaultSingleName`:

```
OLApp.ActiveWindow.Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot Randall! I've also found that if Outlook isn't actually opened that won't work because ActiveWindow will be null, so wrapping it up like this helps too:

```
If Not (oApp.ActiveWindow Is Nothing) Then  'only if there's a window
            oApp.ActiveWindow.Activate  'make sure outlook comes to foreground first
End If
```

Comment: Would that not mean the dialog will be hidden?